# How to update an INT column in every single row in many multi-million row tables efficiently

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Right now my approach is to loop over all the tables and for each table execute the following logic:

1. Truncate the log
2. Check if the row count is greater than 20*BatchSize and the table has no index where the first column is the column I need to update.
3. if the answer is true to both questions - create a filtered non clustered index on the column to be updated and where the column value is OldValue
4. Loop on the table and in every iteration execute a query like this: `UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize) TableX SET MyColumn = NewValue WHERE MyColumn = OldValue`

Before starting the process I prepare the database by:

- Disabling all the constraints
- Setting up the SIMPLE recovery mode

Still, this is very slow.

Note that I have a space constraint - I cannot clone the tables (replacing UPDATE with INSERT and DROP)

I think I should use a more sophisticated check before deciding that an index is not needed. Maybe there are other things I can do to speed up the process.

Ideas are most welcome.

**EDIT**

1. When the table is processed, nobody is using it. Guaranteed.
2. I have already mentioned, the database is moved to SIMPLE recovery mode before the operation.
3. I update the tables in batches of 4,000,000 records using the following SQL statement - `UPDATE TOP (4000000) [CurTable] SET [MyColumn] = @NewValue WHERE [MyColumn] = @OldValue`

The script to do the work actually does nothing - it generates another SQL script, which in turn does the work. Here is the generated script, after I added a few changes advised below, like:

1. Use TABLOCK
2. Use explicit BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT for the batch update statement

So, here is the script (renamed tables):

```
USE [MyDB]
GO
USE [MyDB]
DECLARE @Candidates TABLE (
    TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    Count BIGINT NOT NULL,
    HasIndex BIT NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO @Candidates (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, Count, HasIndex) VALUES
  ('Table1', 'ClientId', 419825723, 1)
 ,('Table2', 'ClientId', 161985636, 1)
 ,('Table3', 'ClientId', 74612857, 0)
 ,('Table4', 'ClientId', 59993404, 0)
 ,('Table5', 'ClientId', 58722785, 0)
 ,('Table6', 'ClientId', 58358957, 0)
 ,('Table7', 'ClientId', 50728845, 0)
 ,('Table8', 'ClientId', 38100412, 0)
 ,('Table9', 'ClientId', 36658839, 0)
 ,('Table10', 'ClientId', 36362842, 0)
...
 ,('Table1000', 'ClientId', 21, 0)

IF (SELECT size/128 FROM sys.database_files where data_space_id = 0) > 999
    DBCC SHRINKFILE ([mydb_log], 1) WITH NO_INFOMSGS

DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @Count INT
DECLARE @HasIndex BIT
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Msg NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 4000000
DECLARE @BatchSizeStr NVARCHAR(10) = CAST(@BatchSize AS NVARCHAR(10))

-- Iterate over all the tables and update them in batches of @BatchSize records
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,Count,HasIndex FROM @Candidates
OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TableName,@ColumnName,@Count,@HasIndex
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- The batch size is less than 5%, plus there is no index starting with the column - create a filtered index
    IF (@Count > @BatchSize * 20) AND (@HasIndex = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql = 'CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_' + @TableName + '_TempCreatedByChangeClientIdFrom14385] ON [' + @TableName + '] ([' + @ColumnName + ']) WHERE [' + @ColumnName + '] = 14385'
        EXEC(@Sql)
    END
    -- Prepare the UPDATE statement
    SET @Sql = 'BEGIN TRAN; UPDATE TOP (' + @BatchSizeStr + ') [' + @TableName + '] WITH (TABLOCK) SET [' + @ColumnName + '] = 9999 WHERE [' + @ColumnName + '] = 14385; COMMIT'
    -- Start the update in batches
    DECLARE @i INT = 0
    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT size/128 FROM sys.database_files where data_space_id = 0) > 999
            DBCC SHRINKFILE ([mydb_log], 1) WITH NO_INFOMSGS
        DECLARE @ts DATETIME = GETUTCDATE()
        EXEC(@Sql)
        DECLARE @Elapsed INT = DATEDIFF(second, @ts, GETUTCDATE())
        DECLARE @CountUpdated INT = @@ROWCOUNT
        SET @i = @i + 1
        SET @Msg = CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ' - ' + @TableName + ' - ' + CAST(@CountUpdated AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '(' + CAST(@Elapsed AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' sec)'
        RAISERROR (@Msg, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT
        IF @CountUpdated < @BatchSize BREAK
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TableName,@ColumnName,@Count,@HasIndex
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
GO
-- Cleanup - drop the created indexes
USE [MyDB]
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @IndexName NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) as TABLE_NAME, name INDEX_NAME
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE name LIKE 'IX_' + OBJECT_NAME(object_id) + '_TempCreatedByChangeClientIdFrom%'
OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TableName,@IndexName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @Sql = 'DROP INDEX [' + @IndexName + '] ON [' + @TableName + ']'
    EXEC(@Sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TableName,@IndexName
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
GO
```

**EDIT 2**

I have ended up using all the advices given in the replies below. Unfortunately, only one reply can be marked as the answer, but I have up-voted all.

So, the final script is pretty big and does the following:

1. Use SIMPLE recovery model
2. Do not truncate the transaction log
3. Uses temporary table to update the target tables
4. `TABLOCK`
5. The individual batch UPDATE statements are wrapped with `BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT`
6. Disables/Enables non clustered indices which include the affected columns
7. Disables/Enables the foreign key constraints which include the affected columns (did not want to disable/enable all of them)

Lots of details. Each table has its own clustered index, so the temporary table schema is different for every table being processed.

Comment: Filtered index slows you down,do you have any clustered index  on table.Could you post sample schema of table

Comment: sorry i misread the question,you are trying to update all tables

Comment: Are you really doing this so frequently that you need to optimize the process? Maybe it's time to look into refactoring the database? Maybe introduce an additional table and the use of surrogate PK/FK so that updating `OldValue` to `NewValue` is a single-row update in one table?

Comment: Not very frequently, rarely actually. But when I do - it is painful.

Comment: What sort of update to the INT are you performing, is it adding a constant? I know this is a little off the wall but if it is you could possible handle via a computed column or a view.

Comment: Random thought passing by: I wonder if setting the database to [single user mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598(v=sql.110).aspx) would have any effect on performance. (Based on your comment that "the database is not in use during that operation".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does runtime differ when you don’t inlcude the index work? Consider:

- To build the index, SQL must perform a table scan
- You then update the column the index is based on, requiring both a table and an index update
- You then have to drop the index (trivial, if non-clusterd)

Without an index:

- SQL performs a full table scan, updating only those rows that need to be updated
- No Index work required

If there are a LOT of rows to update (thus the transaction log truncation), a tactic I have used is to “chunkify” the data, something like so:

- Create a temp table, include an identity column
- Read the target table, load the primay key for each row to be updated into the temp table
- Do an “Update Target inner join Temp where TempId between @LoopCounter @Loopcounter + X” type query between the two tables
- WHILE Loop over this, incrementing @Loopcounter by X until @@rowcount = 0

If you don't have primary keys defined on the table(s), well, then you have a different problem.

Good thing you don’t have to wrap everything in a transaction! (…right?)

Comment: Of course, no transaction. The rows are updated in batches, which are less than 5% of the table. Hence I have reasons to believe that if I create an index it is used. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Depends on volume, ratio of "to be update" vs. not, and other subtleties. If you have a test environment, try our the tactics discussed, see what works best in your circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few tips  other than what you have already..

1.Don't truncate the log.File growth is an expensive operation.
2.Try using one of the locking hints if you are ok,so that SQL will acquire Table lock instead of row lock and escalating  later

```
update sales.OrderDetails 
with (tablock)
set productid=productid+1
```

3.Further,i recommend changing your query to be wrapped in a transaction to minimize log flushes.

```
begin tran
UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize) TableX 
SET MyColumn = NewValue
WHERE MyColumn = OldValue

Commit --Now all log flush to disk will happen only at the end of transaction,ensure this is not big a transaction
```

More  depends on what is  your wait type while updating .For instance,if your wait type is write log or anything related to log like Flushing log..Then your batch size in transaction is big.`You will have to troubleshoot based on wait types` using below DMC to start with..

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_query_requests where session_id='your session'
```

Comment: I have a space constraint. Cannot allow the log to grow too big. TABLOCK is a good advice, I can definitely use it. The database is not in use during that operation.

Comment: transaction log space will be reused,log truncate wont help if a single transaction exceeds space

Comment: So, in SIMPLE recovery mode I do not need to shrink the log? Once the previous transaction is done its log space will be reused? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: .You should not shrink log.In simple recovery model,transaction log space will be reused automatically once a check point occurs, provided there is no open transaction preventing it..Even if you shrink log space wont be reclaimed if there is an open transaction..https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189573.aspx

Comment: No open transactions. Do I have to do anything to cause a check point to occur?

Comment: it occurs automatically based on reasons mentioned in above link,but dont truncate log .your better change your single update query to smaller batches update as mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Best way to update multi million records is with a SELECT statement that populates a second table. You have to take care when doing this. Instructions below.

**Simple Case**

For a table w/out a clustered index, during a time w/out concurrent DML:

SELECT *, new_col = 1 INTO clone.BaseTable FROM dbo.BaseTable

recreate indexes, constraints, etc on new table
switch old and new w/ ALTER SCHEMA ... TRANSFER.
drop old table

If you can't create a clone schema, a different table name in the same schema will do. Remember to rename all your constraints and triggers (if applicable) after the switch.

**Non-simple Case**

First, recreate your BaseTable with the same name under a different schema, eg clone.BaseTable. Using a separate schema will simplify the rename process later.

Include the clustered index, if applicable. Remember that primary keys and unique constraints may be clustered, but not necessarily so.
Include identity columns and computed columns, if applicable.
Include your new INT column, wherever it belongs.
Do not include any of the following:
triggers
foreign key constraints
non-clustered indexes/primary keys/unique constraints
check constraints or default constraints. Defaults don't make much of difference, but we're trying to keep things minimal.
Then, test your insert w/ 1000 rows:

-- assuming an IDENTITY column in BaseTable

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT clone.BaseTable ON
GO
INSERT clone.BaseTable WITH (TABLOCK) (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT TOP 1000 Col1, Col2, Col3 = -1
FROM dbo.BaseTable
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT clone.BaseTable OFF
```

Examine the results. If everything appears in order:

truncate the clone table
make sure the database in in bulk-logged or simple recovery model
perform the full insert.
This will take a while, but not nearly as long as an update. Once it completes, check the data in the clone table to make sure it everything is correct.

Then, recreate all non-clustered primary keys/unique constraints/indexes and foreign key constraints (in that order). Recreate default and check constraints, if applicable. Recreate all triggers. Recreate each constraint, index or trigger in a separate batch. eg:

```
ALTER TABLE clone.BaseTable ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_BaseTable UNIQUE (Col2)
GO
-- next constraint/index/trigger definition here
Finally, move dbo.BaseTable to a backup schema and clone.BaseTable to the dbo schema (or wherever your table is supposed to live).

-- -- perform first true-up operation here, if necessary
-- EXEC clone.BaseTable_TrueUp
-- GO
-- -- create a backup schema, if necessary
-- CREATE SCHEMA backup_20100914
-- GO
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  ALTER SCHEMA backup_20100914 TRANSFER dbo.BaseTable
  -- -- perform second true-up operation here, if necessary
  -- EXEC clone.BaseTable_TrueUp
  ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER clone.BaseTable
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() -- add more info here if necessary
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
GO
```

If you need to free-up disk space, you may drop your original table at this time, though it may be prudent to keep it around a while longer.

Needless to say, this is ideally an offline operation. If you have people modifying data while you perform this operation, you will have to perform a true-up operation with the schema switch. I recommend creating a trigger on dbo.BaseTable to log all DML to a separate table. Enable this trigger before you start the insert. Then in the same transaction that you perform the schema transfer, use the log table to perform a true-up. Test this first on a subset of the data! Deltas are easy to screw up.

Hope this help,

Answer (score 1):

I know it seems counter intuitive but disable any index on the column
The overhead of index maintenance row by row is not worth the search time
An index adds significant overhead to the update
The index is likely to get badly fragmented anyway

```
select 1  
while (@@rowcount > 0) 
begin 
   update top (10000)
   set intCol = 12 
   from table 
   where intCol <> 12 
end
```

enable any index on the column

if no one else is in the table then you can use a bigger number and

```
with (tablock)
```

In the first few top (x) even a column scan is going to find the rows pretty quickly.  So an index is definitely not worth the overhead of index maintenance.

If you have an index it will be of more value after few top (x).  But after a few top (x) you also have more index fragmentation.  Once you get to 30% fragmentation you might as well do a scan.

The part of the index you need to use where intCol <> 12 is the part of the index that has been hammered.

Comment: @mark As I clearly stated the "The overhead of index maintenance row by row is not worth the search time".  What do you lose by giving it a try?

Comment: I now disable all the non clustered indices containing the column in question on all the tables having at least 1,000,000 records.